# How do I change the axes?

Tags: code-request, vector-calculus, webmathematica, code

```
Clear[y, curveplotter]
curveplotter[y_] = {0, y, f[y]}; 
curve = ParametricPlot3D[curveplotter[y], {y, 0, 3.5}]; 
threedims = Axes3D[4]; 
curveplot = Show[threedims, curve, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> 
CMView, Boxed -> False]
```

I know this is in the yz-axis, and I was wondering how I can rotate this in the y-axis, and the z-axis (two separate examples?) I'm trying to review an assignment but I don't remember how to alter the code to see this graph about these two axes?

Comment: Do you mean a surface of revolution?  Have you seen `RevolutionPlot3D`?

Comment: Neither `Axes3D` nor `CMView` are defined by Mathematica. Their definitions might be important to the question.